# Spring security - Basic auth

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, basic-authentication

I'm trying to insert data using a POST request but I'm getting a 403 error. When I use GET, basic authentication works. For testing I use Fiddler.

What's the problem?

Security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER").and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                    .password("password")
                    .roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Request - POST:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Length: 200
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
```

Request body:

```
{"name" : "name1",
"description" : "desc1"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably CSRF, which spring security enables by default. Look for a X-XSRF-TOKEN header in your GET request, and use that header and value in your POST.

Think twice before you do this, but you can disable csrf with

```
http.csrf().disable()
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/web-app-security.html#csrf

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class HelloWebSecurityConfiguration
   extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth
      .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
  }
}
```

Source: http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/

Comment: Not too clear: are you trying to log in/insert data etc using a form and POST and its not working with SpringSecurity but GET does?